# Change android viewpager tab title programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

as per question title, is it possible to change a ViewPager tab title programmatically?

Comment: Are you using `PagerSlidingTabStrip` or just simple tabs of the actionbar?

Comment: I'm using the android support v4 library

Comment: Can you show your code, how do you add tabs?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.addTab(
                    tabHost.newTab()
                            .setText(pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this)
            );
        }

Comment: I can set the initial title correctly! I need to change it programmatically!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method: getTabWidget from tabhost, get tab by index, and the find title view by id, like this

```
TextView title = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(yourTabIndex).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
title.setText(yourNewTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
tv.setText("New Tab Text");
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this is what you want

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(int index)
```

It worked for me I think it would work for you too

Comment: Hello, no! I think you misunderstood my question! this is for change the current tab programmatically. I need to change the title of the tab!